# CIFS mount suddenly stopped working error 22

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have been using the following fstab entry on my ubuntu 22.04 client, for mounting a directory on an Ubuntu 20.04 server:

```
//nas/plex /home/USER/nas/plex cifs  uid=0,credentials=/home/USER/somefile,iocharset=utf8,noperm,noauto,user 0 0
```

Something has changed, and now this no longer works.  The error in dmesg is:

> [ 3679.254486] CIFS: Attempting to mount \nas\plex
> [ 3679.259733] CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22

I have tried removing each option separately, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the error code `22` indicates a networking issue. The first thing I usually try is to replace the network name with its IP address; i.e.

```
//192.168.1.55/plex /home/USER/nas/plex cifs  uid=0,credentials=/home/USER/somefile,iocharset=utf8,noperm,noauto,user 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching, my Ubuntu server must have changed SMB versions.  I added "vers=3.0" to the options.  Now it mounts as before.